# TikZ, babel and quotes problem in marginpar

Tags: tikz-pgf, punctuation, babel

The following MWE works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
%\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate["$A$" below] (A) at (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

foo \marginpar{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate["$A$" below] (A) at (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

However, if I uncomment `babel`, the quotes in the marginpar cause an error:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/"$A$"below' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

What can I do (except using the longer standard syntax instead of the short form with quotes)?

Comment: It appears to be a bug, probably due to the catcode for ".  You can use label={[below]$A$} instead and lose the quotes.

Comment: But why is the catcode different in marginpars than in normal paragraphs? Something to do with moving elements and fragile/robust?

Comment: Interestingly, it doesn't like being in a \parbox, \mbox or \savebox, but is fine with a minipage, \hbox or \vbox.

Comment: Please do not use `minimal` for examples. It is not suitable at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch the shorthand off before creating the marginal image and back on afterwards, but this needs to be done before `\marginpar`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate["$A$" below] (A) at (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

foo \shorthandoff{"}\marginpar{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate["$A$" below] (A) at (0,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: foo A]